# how to login to instagram on dev computer

Tags: php, wordpress, api, instagram, access-token

I am trying to create a wordpress plugin that will display images from my company's instagram account. My dev computer is on my desktop computer behind the company's firewall. My understanding (which could be wrong) is that the page will have to go to the instagram site to get an access token, and then the token is returned to a specified redirect url. Is there any way I can get access to this while behind the firewall on my local desktop (that obviously has no direct connection to the outside)?

Comment: Your redirect_url doesn't have to be accessible to Facebook. It just has to work on your computer.

Comment: It's the client that actually does the redirect so any URL the client (your computer/broswer) can access will work. Their service simply returns a header with a URL the client should go to. So as long as you can access internet, it should work. If you can't access internet, it obviously won't work.

Comment: If you don't have connection - how do you expect to get images?

Comment: @u_mulder I can't tell instagram to redirect the page to http://localhost, which is where I'm creating the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your local URL (localhost) for your app in the Instagram developer portal under the security tab.